# Flutter: How to convert a string to a valid JSON format in dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This is the string I'm getting from my API.

[{name: Harry, phoneNumber: 9876543210, userPost: [{_id: 618b625715a5af04707ef687, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Table, quantity: 47, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}, {name: Peter, phoneNumber: 9999999999, userPost: [{_id: 618cc96afcaa83282844ff99, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Chair, quantity: 60, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}]

Later I found out that this string should be in this format

[{"name": "Harry", "phoneNumber": "9876543210", "userPost": [{"_id": "618b625715a5af04707ef687", "productGroup": "Furniture", "productName": "Table", "quantity": "47", "fromDate": "01-01-2021", "toDate": "31-12-2021"}]}, {"name": "Peter", "phoneNumber": "9999999999", "userPost": [{"_id": "618cc96afcaa83282844ff99", "productGroup": "Furniture", "productName": "Chair", "quantity": "60", "fromDate": "01-01-2021", "toDate": "31-12-2021"}]}]

for json.decode() to run without error.

I'm unable to convert this string to a valid JSON format. Here's my code =>

```
   body= val.data['rslt'].toString();
   setUser(body);

Future<List<User>> setUser(String jsonString) async{
    List<User> list;
    print('encoding');
    print(jsonString);
    String encodedStr= json.encode(jsonString);
    print(encodedStr);
    List<dynamic> data = json.decode(encodedStr) as List<dynamic>;
    print(data);
    list = data.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
    listDis=list;

    print("List Size: ${list.length}");
    return list;
  }



class User {
  final String name;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final PostOffer postOffer;

  const User({
    required this.name,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.postOffer
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
        name: json['name'].toString(),
        phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'].toString(),
        postOffer: PostOffer.fromJson(json)

    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {

    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();

      data['name'] = this.name;
      data['phoneNumber'] = this.phoneNumber;
    if (this.postOffer != null) {
      data['postOffer'] = this.postOffer.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
  
}


class PostOffer {
  final String? productGroup;
  final String? productName;
  final String? quantity;
  final String? fromDate;
  final String? toDate;

  PostOffer({required this.productGroup, required this.productName, required this.quantity, required this.fromDate, required this.toDate});

  factory PostOffer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return PostOffer(
        productGroup:parsedJson['productGroup'] as String?,
        productName:parsedJson['productName'] as String?,
        quantity:parsedJson['quantity'] as String?,
        fromDate:parsedJson['fromDate'] as String?,
        toDate:parsedJson['toDate'] as String?
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
   Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['productGroup']= this.productGroup;
    data['productName']= this.productName;
    data['quantity']= this.quantity;
    data['fromDate']= this.fromDate;
    data['toDate']= this.toDate;

  return data;
  }
  
}
```

When I use json.encode() function, it converts this string

[{name: Harry, phoneNumber: 9876543210, userPost: [{_id: 618b625715a5af04707ef687, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Table, quantity: 47, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}, {name: Peter, phoneNumber: 9999999999, userPost: [{_id: 618cc96afcaa83282844ff99, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Chair, quantity: 60, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}]

to this

"[{name: Harry, phoneNumber: 9876543210, userPost: [{_id: 618b625715a5af04707ef687, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Table, quantity: 47, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}, {name: Peter, phoneNumber: 9999999999, userPost: [{_id: 618cc96afcaa83282844ff99, productGroup: Furniture, productName: Chair, quantity: 60, fromDate: 01-01-2021, toDate: 31-12-2021}]}]"

instead to

[{"name": "Harry", "phoneNumber": "9876543210", "userPost": [{"_id": "618b625715a5af04707ef687", "productGroup": "Furniture", "productName": "Table", "quantity": "47", "fromDate": "01-01-2021", "toDate": "31-12-2021"}]}, {"name": "Peter", "phoneNumber": "9999999999", "userPost": [{"_id": "618cc96afcaa83282844ff99", "productGroup": "Furniture", "productName": "Chair", "quantity": "60", "fromDate": "01-01-2021", "toDate": "31-12-2021"}]}]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly barking up the wrong tree. The API is delivering broken data to you. It's defective. It's buggy.

You contact the maker of the API and tell them their product is defective. And you ask them when they plan to fix it.

If you buy a car and it's not green like you ordered it to be, then you go back to the dealer and complain. You don't start trying to get all green pens, crayons and spraycans in the house and try to wing it.

There is a bug. Report it. You cannot fix it, it's not your code.

---

That said, the "json" (not actually valid json) string you get from the API is not only broken in that regard, it's also broken in a few other ways. I would highly recommend thinking about going with a different API vendor if possible, this seems to be pretty amateur.